Is it OK to have my DocuSign test account attached to a different domain than the production account I am about to create?
I am an IT DevOps contractor and have developed an internal tool for one of my clients. Note that I am not an ISV, this tool is strictly for and belongs to the client. My DocuSign test account is attached to my email "@mybusiness.com". Soon we will promote this to production and will need to create a production account using an email "@mycustomerbusiness.com".
I am wondering if DocuSign requires/assumes that the test account and production account are attached to the same company domain. Said another way:
Is this use of 2 unrelated domains going to cause us any problems during the go live process?
If yes, how can we mitigate the issue?
Is it going to cause us any problems in future rounds of development and testing?
I researched in the DocuSign developer center and searched StackOverflow. I haven't tried it because the point of the question is to avoid trying it and making a mess :). Thank you.

Need to ask a single question, this is a bit broad.

When you build integrations for Docusign they are available to all accounts in the same environment (developer/test/demo/sandbox vs. production).
So, you don't need to worry about the email domain or which account etc.
As long as you go-live with the IK in any production account, that IK will now be available for ALL production accounts.
